# Java Optional why not an ifNotPresent method?

Tags: java-8, option-type

I was wondering why on the Java8 API the Optional class have the method `ifPresent(Consumer< T> consumer)` and not the `ifNotPresent(Runnable** consumer)`?

What's the intent of the API? Isn't it to emulate the functional pattern matching?

** Java doesn't have a zero argument void functional interface...

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Comment: It is because the computation should be side effect free, so if I need to execute something when the computation fail, in the case it doesn't fail I will do nothing with the result, but lose it...ok now it's clear, thank you!

Comment: `.ifPresentOrElse` is in the pipeline for jdk9: [see mailing list discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-February/031223.html)

Comment: `Runnable` is indeed the zero-arg void functional interface. And the second argument  of the new JDK 9 `Optional.ifPresentOrElse` is `Runnable`.

Comment: I know about the Runnable but it was created for another scope, it's just a matter to make the intent of a function explicit :) cheers

Answer (score 10):

As Misha said, this feature [will come with jdk9](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-February/031223.html) in the form of a [`ifPresentOrElse`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/client/jdk/file/5e43d8456cec/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java#l166) method.

```
/**
 * If a value is present, performs the given action with the value,
 * otherwise performs the given empty-based action.
 *
 * @param action the action to be performed, if a value is present
 * @param emptyAction the empty-based action to be performed, if no value is
 *        present
 * @throws NullPointerException if a value is present and the given action
 *         is {@code null}, or no value is present and the given empty-based
 *         action is {@code null}.
 * @since 9
 */
public void ifPresentOrElse(Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction) {
    if (value != null) {
        action.accept(value);
    } else {
        emptyAction.run();
    }
}
```